# Why is apparmor logging ALLOWED cases for LibreOffice?

Tags: logs, libreoffice, apparmor

I'm using Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster). I'm seeing quite a few `/var/log/messages` messages involving apparmor, e.g.:

```
Oct 29 12:05:20 my_host_name kernel: [232254.998790] audit: type=1400 audit(1572343520.921:6063): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="chmod" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/mnt/sdb3/home-joeuser/.local/share/recently-used.xbel" pid=32533 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Questions:

1. Why am I getting these messages at all?
2. How do I make them go away?

Answer (score 1):

These logs come from **apparmor**.

I am new to this software, but basically appparmor has a rule (i.e. setting) for LibreOffice defining a *complaint mode*. 
When libreoffice is trying to write certain files a warning is logged.

You can stop this logs by removing the app-armor rule for libreoffice.

Refer for instance to these links for more details:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor
- https://linuxhint.com/apparmor-profiles-ubuntu/

Comment: Do you know where this rule is defined? I couldn't (easily) find it under `/etc/apparmor`

Comment: _/etc/apparmor.d_ I guess. To remove a rule you have to link it to /etc/apparmor.d/disabled. But I am not familiar enough to help you. You'd better read the doc.

Comment: But where in there? I couldn't find an apparently-relevant file.